# How can I plot only a specific range of a curve, while having axis with higher limits?

Tags: matlab, plot

I need to plot a section of curve, using MATLAB. But I need my axes to be larger than the part I am showing.

For example, I have the following data:

```
x = 0:50
y = 0.5*x
```

I would like to plot this data from `x=0` to `x=20`, with `xlim([0 50])`.

[image: This image should help explain]

Just to clarify, I do not want to change the range of values of `x`, I just want to change what is shown on the graph.

Comment: It seems trivial to start with `x=0:20`... You already know about `xlim`, I don't see where the problem could be here. How do you normally plot a curve? Maybe that is where you are suck? Please share some code so we know where you're at.

Comment: I can't change the values of x (as I need them later on), so I can't set x=0:20. I need the xlim to be higher than 20, but I only want to show a small portion of the curve. I could try changing my script to allow me to change the values of x. I'll try that now.

Comment: I have edited your question to match my current understanding of your problem. Does this correspond to what you're thinking? Please revert my edit if it's not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have some data

```
x = 0:50;
y = 0.5*x;
```

and you would like to plot only a part of it, say everything where `x<=20`. You can do as follows:

```
index = x <= 20;
plot(x(index), y(index))
xlim(x([1,end])) % set the x-axis limit to the range of all your `x` values
ylim([min(y),max(y)]) % set the y-axis limit to the range of all your `y` values
```

Comment: actually, you don't necessarily need to do the indexing. Setting the limits with `xlim` + `ylim` (or with `axis` jointly setting x and y axis) is enough but will force Matlab to plot everything first and than "zoom" into the figure. This might be unhandy if you have really a lot of data to plot

Comment: @max: feel free to post your own answer. I don't think your solution would solve what OP is after.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
x = 0:20
y = 0.5*x
plot(x,y)
xlim([0 50]) % This will set x-axis to the desired range
ylim([min(y) max(y)])
```